# Does Zend have something like {strip} in Smarty?

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, strip, zend-view

Smarty has a {strip} function:

```
{strip}
<table border='0'>
 <tr>
  <td>
   Hello world
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
{/strip}
```

Which outputs:

```
<table border='0'><tr><td>Hello world</td></tr></table>
```

I also want to do this in Zend (to reduce the amount of bites send on each request), without installing Smarty.

However, I don't want to add code to every Layout / .phtml file, so a frontcontroller plugin would be nice.

Comment: I did find http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Filter_Minify_Html+-+Nick+Daugherty but this is not implemented yet, so the question remains

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use the same regex that Smarty uses. It's quite simple:

```
function strip($str, $replace = ' ')
{
    return preg_replace('#\s+#', $replace, $str);
}
```

Comment: But make a view helper for it to make it DRY :)